# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable al intentar imprimir el primer índice de cada lista

Tags: python

```
print('Ingrese la cantidad de amigos: ')
amigos = int(input())
print('Ingrese la cantidad de platillos: ')
cantidad = int(input())

total = 0 #Contador para llevar la suma de los precios de los platos.
b = 0 #Contador para ver si la cantidad de platillos es igual a la 
solicitada.
a = ['', '','', '','', '', '', ''] #Lista para platillos
m = ['', '','', '','', '', '', ''] #Lista para precios 
s = ['', '','', '','', '', '', ''] #Lista para cantidad de platillos 
g = 0 #Para ver cuantos platillos hay en la lista 
p = 0 #Para ver cuantos precios hay en la lista
q = 0 #Para ver cuantos platillos pidieron
f = 0 #jeje


print('Propina: ')
propina = int(input())
prop = (propina * total)/100
totalC = total - prop
alo = totalC / amigos
print("-----------------------------------------------------------------")
print("-----------------------------------------------------------------")
print("SISTEMA PARA CÁLCULO DE PAGOS")
print("")
print("No. de amigos " , amigos)
print("CANTIDAD          PLATILLO                    PRECIO")
print("")

for x in range(0, f):
    print(s[x],  "               ",  g[x] ,  "          " ,  "          Q. ",  p[x])

for x in range(0, len[x] - f):
    print("0",  "      ",  "         -" ,  "           ",  "             -")
```

error

> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

lo que estoy tratando de hacer 
es imprimir cada índice el los ciclos pero no me deja por algún motivo.

Comment: El problema es que para coger la longitud de una lista, se emplea `len(lista)` pero aquí ni los paréntesis son los correctos, ni es x una lista.

Comment: `g` y `p` son enteros e intentas indizar sobre ellos con `g[x]`  y   `p[x]` en el `print` del primer `for`... ¿No deberías indizar sobre `a` y `m` y no sobre `g` y `p`?